# Download files with server side encryption SSE AES256 using boto3

Tags: python, amazon-s3, boto3, amazon-kms

I can list the files in the source bucket but when I try to download them I am getting "Client error 403" , the source team has server side encryption AES256 enabled.
So when I try :

client.download_fileobj(bucket, file, f, ExtraArgs={"ServerSideEncryption": "AES256"})

I am getting ValueError: Invalid extra_args key 'ServerSideEncryption', must be one of: VersionId, SSECustomerAlgorithm, SSECustomerKey, SSECustomerKeyMD5, RequestPayer
How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Can you post the bucket policy and the IAM permissions attached to your IAM user/role?

Comment: @jellycsc for my role on my end I have S3fullacess and assume role permissions. The source team said they gave me full access to their bucket . They say there is server side encryption enabled and asked me to add --sse AES256

Answer (score 1):

It should work without mentioning `ExtraArgs={"ServerSideEncryption": "AES256"}`.

When SSE algorithm is AES256, you don't need to mention that while downloading object, only while uploading it.

While downloading it, you need to make sure that the credentials, you are using to download the object, have access to the key that is used to encrypt the object.